# Proper way to use axios with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm creating little app using React, Redux and MongoDB.
Unfortunately I'm having problems with using **axios** with **redux**. I tried using it inside reduces like this:

```
export function users(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {

     case 'USER_ADD':
       {
         axios.post('http://localhost:4200/users/add/post', {user: 
         action.user}).then(() => {
           return {
             ...state,
             items: [
               ...state.users,
               action.user
             ]
           }
         }).catch(err => console.log(err));
         break;
       }
     .........
```

But it doesn't work. Then I moved axios to my action creators, so it looks like this:

```
export function addUser(user) {

   return function (dispatch) {
     axios.post('http://localhost:4200/users/add/user', {user:user})
       .then(() => dispatch({
         type: USER_ADD,
         user: user
       })).catch(err => console.log(err));
   }
 }
```

It posts new document to the mongo database but it also gives me error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. And yes I'm using redux thunk ;)

Can anybody tell me where is the problem? Feel free to ask for more code, not sure what else can be useful.

**EDIT:**

I'm using redux-thunk like that:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';


const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: have you imported redux-thunk?

Comment: Yes, I'm editing my post right now to show how I did it

Comment: Side note: Reducers should be pure functions without side effects so putting axios there is really bad idea.

Comment: As I said, I moved axios to action creators so they are only returning new state ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code. I think you are not creating the store properly.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore,combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';

let reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
// applyMiddleware supercharges createStore with middleware:
const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I already used combineReducers. Those reducers I import from './reducers' are reducers combined into one. Do I need to combine it again?

Comment: @kreha no you don't need then.

Comment: @Kreha are you getting the same error? please post some details about error as well.

Comment: I'm gonna put everything on github for you in just a second and post screenshot with error

Comment: Alright, I solved the problem. I forgot to rewrite one of the acrion creators and it caused this error ;p After commenting it error is gone. Everything should be fine after rewriting it. In case of any other problems I will get back here. Thanks for the help :)